# how can i fix my error in my function?

Tags: python

where is the mistake in my functions?
i got an error
def

Answer (score 2):

In `return compute_confusion_matrix`, you return the function itself when you should call it:

```
return compute_confusion_matrix('truth.txt', 'prediction.txt')
```

Comment: i got an error with open(file1) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '!truth.txt'

Comment: please check my updated question above in the post maybe i understood the question wrong ,, as you see in the question i tried to read the dictionary in  compute_confusion_matrix without using  read_classification_from_file()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assume that compute_confusion_matrix() takes 'truth.txt' and 'prediction.txt' by default, change the def to:

```
def compute_confusion_matrix(file1='!truth.txt', 
                             file2='!prediction.txt', 
                             pos_tag=True, 
                             neg_tag=False):
```

Then call it directly:

```
return compute_confusion_matrix()
```

Comment: i got the same error with open(file1) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'truth.txt'

Comment: please check my updated question above in the post maybe i understood the question wrong ,, as you see in the question i tried to read the dictionary in  compute_confusion_matrix without using  read_classification_from_file()

Comment: it seems very odd to prepend "!" in a file name, since that is usually read as "not" something. Would recommend prepending with "_" instead if you're trying to push a file to the top, alphabetically speaking.

Comment: still i am getting the same error, i updated my function in the post ,could you please check it